# Does there exist this special kind of homeomorphism?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, existence-theorems

Let  $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^n, n\geq 2,$ are two different shaped spindles. One is thick and one is thin. (Sorry for my unprofessional statements. Unsure about how to say it rigorously.) So there are homeomorphisms between $A$ and $B$.
  My question is:
   Is there such an homeomorphism $H$ that can be realized as 
$$H(x_1,...,x_n)=(h_1(x_1),...,h_n(x_n)),$$ where
$$h_q:A_q  \to B_q$$ and $A_q, B_q$ are the projection of $A, B$ to the $q$-th coordinate respectively?
   Visually,  $H$ maps coordinate-paralleling lines to paralleling lines and coordinate-paralleling sheets to paralleling sheets.
Thanks.

Comment: I might misunderstand the question. Consider "П" and "•". These are two compact, connected simply-connected sets. All the sections of the latter by horizontal lines are connected, but not so for the former.

Comment: @BorisBukh Thanks for your example. I was trying to consider two "regular" subsets, such as squares and disks. I added the condition: nonempty interior on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I'm probably being naive, but do you have a reference for your first statement?

Comment: A closed thickening of the 2-sphere and a closed 3-ball are a counterexample to your first statement as is. Should simply-connected be replaced with contractible? Even if so, I'm not convinced they're aren't counterexamples.

Comment: Do you simply mean self-homeomorphisms of an $X$ onto itself?

Comment: As the Q. is stated, $A$ and $B$ may have zero homeomorphisms. Perhaps you like to assume that they are homeomorphic to start with.

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski  and PVAL Thanks a lot for your comments and sorry for my lousy statements. I simplified the question to avoid talking unsure topological things as a non-topologist.

Comment: @PVAL You are right. I simplified the question. Sorry for MY ignorance.

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski I found myself trapped in the description. I'll just try when $A$ is a unit cube and $B$ is the unit ball.